# Redirect after login laravel 7 gives me white page, no errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using Laravel 7.

I have customized  method for login in LoginController
which check's if you type is "Applicant" or "Business" and redirect to different route, should be very basic.

Now after login it's gives me blank white page, no error on
Laravel log or laravel dev server.

```
protected function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

        $user = Auth::user();

        if (Auth::check()) {
            if ($user->userType === 'Applicant') {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }

            if ($user->userType === 'Business') {
                return redirect()->route('dashboard');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

web.php:

```
Route::get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('auth.login');
Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard')->name('dashboard');
```

HomeController

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}

public function dashboard()
{
    return view('dashboard');
}
```

---- Added Home.blade.php ----

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div id="app" class="ml-1 mr-1 border border-dark">
      <dashboard v-bind:u-Id="{{ Auth::user()->id }}"
        v-bind:p-Id="{{ auth()->user()->profile()->first()->id }}"
        > </dashboard>

</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: please add your home.blade,php..

Comment: Most likely one of the outer conditions (`if (Auth::attempt($credentials))` or `if (Auth::check())`) is false and the applicant/business check isn't executed at all.

Comment: Why is your `login` method `protected` instead of `public`?

Comment: not all paths return something, if the credentials are not good it will just sit there

Comment: @Rwd - It was copy paste, Changed to public, did not make any different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not overriding the login method for this. Instead, I would suggest using the [authenticated "hook"](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#included-authenticating):

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->userType === 'Applicant') {
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

    if ($user->userType === 'Business') {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Comment: that code was working only if I use seeded user which are already db.
When I create new user, after login, he will redirect to main page "/".

Comment: I think, I have found the problem: when I create manually user, in My RegisterController, I create   $token['email_verification_token'] = Str::random(64);
but not in my seeder. I will add it and see if it makes any different.

Comment: @MikroMike Is the `userType` definitely set as either `Applicant` or `Business` in the database?

Comment: yes.   $table->string('userType')->default('applicant')->nullable(); And
In UserFactory:  'userType' => $faker->randomElement(['Applicant', 'Business']),

Comment: @MikroMike Sorry, I don't think I made myself clear then. Can you check that the manual user you've created definitely has that value (not just that it should) i.e. checking in the database itself or doing `dd($user->userType)`. Realistically, this is starting to go outside the scope of this question and it might be worth creating a new question.

Comment: here is typo:  ->default('applicant'), should be Applicant

Answer (score 0):

It is more logical to have a default redirect page, like `home`. I think below code is more sensible.

```
protected function login(Request $request){
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {

        $user = Auth::user();

        if (Auth::check()) {

            if ($user->userType === 'Business') {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');

            } else {
                return redirect()->route('home');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have another default redirect page, use `elseif` and add your default page in `else` section.